# Regex to extract time information from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm receiving data from a third party device. I need to extract two pieces of information. I think I need to use a Regular Expression, but I don't know anything of this.

Below you can find a few example strings:

```
TN        12  1 17:45:19.90400  7173
TN         4  4 17:45:20.51800  7173
TN        13  1 17:45:24.03200  7173
TN         5  4 17:45:26.06300  7173
TN         6  4 17:45:29.28700  7173
TN        14  1 17:45:31.03200  7173
```

From each of these strings I need to extract two pieces of data:

- the time
- the number before the time

So the data I'm looking for is this:

```
1 and 17:45:19.90400
4 and 17:45:20.51800
1 and 17:45:24.03200
4 and 17:45:26.06300
4 and 17:45:29.28700
1 and 17:45:31.03200
```

The number will always be present and it will always be 1, 2, 3 or 4.
The time will also be the same format but I'm not sure if there will be single digit hours. So I don't know if 9 o'clock will be displayed as

> 9 or 09

Any suggestions on how I can extract this using a RegEx?

Thanks

Comment: You could always just split on whitespace and take the items at indexes 2 and 3, i.e: `var parts = input.Split(); var number = parts[2]; var time = parts[3];`

Comment: The data is at a fixed position. Regex would be beneficial if you dodn't know where it was in the line and you need to find it by its pattern. But you *know* where it is, so call `Substring` on the line and extract the segment you need.  In this case, it looks like `Substring(16, 14)` for the time and `Substring(13, 2).TrimStart()` for the preceding number. `int.Parse` on the latter will work if it's zero-prefixed and `TrimStart` accounts for non-padded numbers.

Comment: You have fixed column width data which really what Regex is not intended to be. Probably better to read one line at a time and then use the string SubString() method to get start and end of fixed width column.

Comment: Imo, in this situation `RegEx` isn't really suitable. `RegEx` is usually used to check the pattern of a string. If you wanted to ensure that the string fits the format first, you could use it, but to extract the information you'll have to parse it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My usual approach to this is to create a class that represents the data we want to capture, and give it a static `Parse` method that takes in an input string and returns an instance of the class populated with data from the string. Then we can just loop through the lines and populate a list of our custom class with data from each line.

For example:

```
class TimeData
{
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public static TimeData Parse(string input)
    {
        var timeData = new TimeData();
        int number;
        TimeSpan time;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) return timeData;

        var parts = input.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (parts.Length > 2 && int.TryParse(parts[2], out number))
        {
            timeData.Number = number;
        }

        if (parts.Length > 3 && TimeSpan.TryParseExact(parts[3], "hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.fffff", 
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out time))
        {
            timeData.Time = time;
        }

        return timeData;
    }
}
```

Now we can just loop through the list of strings, call `Parse` on each line, and end up with a new list of objects that contain the `Time` and associated `Number` for each line. Also note that, by using a `TimeSpan` to represent the time, we now have properties for all the parts, like `Hour`, `Minute`, `Seconds`, `Milliseconds`, `TotalMinutes`, etc:

```
var fileLines = new List<string>
{
    "TN        12  1 17:45:19.90400  7173",
    "TN         4  4 17:45:20.51800  7173",
    "TN        13  1 17:45:24.03200  7173",
    "TN         5  4 17:45:26.06300  7173",
    "TN         6  4 17:45:29.28700  7173",
    "TN        14  1 17:45:31.03200  7173",
};

List<TimeData> allTimeData = fileLines.Select(TimeData.Parse).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you  for this graceful solution @Rufus L